# ggplot2: refer to data supplied to ggplot(...) inside later calls to geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I often encounter scenarios where different geoms need to see a subset of the data supplied to the `data` argument of the initial call to `ggplot()`.

Usually this takes place in the context of vizualizing something after a long chain where I  don't actually need the data saved in my workspace but my current workaround is to do so then refer to it in each geom explicitly, for example:

```
(
    #...
    # long chain
    # ...
) -> to_plot
(
    ggplot()
    + geom_ribbon(
        data = (
            to_plot #using intermediate object saved to workspace
            %>% dplyr::filter(
                cells_or_boots=='bootss'
            )
        )
        , mapping = aes(
            x = x
            , ymin = lo
            , ymax = hi
        )
    )
    + geom_line(
        data = (
            to_plot #using intermediate object saved to workspace
            %>% dplyr::filter(
                cells_or_boots=='cells'
            )
        )
        , mapping = aes(
            x = x
            , y = mean
        )
    )
)
```

Is there something like `dplyr::cur_data()` for ggplot2 that would enable something like:

```
(
    #...
    # long chain
    # ...
    %>% ggplot()
    + geom_ribbon(
        data = (
            ggplot_cur_data()  #place for hoped-for dplyr::cur_data() equivalent
            %>% dplyr::filter(
                cells_or_boots=='boots'
            )
        )
        , mapping = aes(
            x = x
            , ymin = lo
            , ymax = hi
        )
    )
    + geom_line(
        data = (
            ggplot_cur_data()  #place for hoped-for dplyr::cur_data() equivalent
            %>% dplyr::filter(
                cells_or_boots=='cells'
            )
        )
        , mapping = aes(
            x = x
            , y = mean
        )
    )
)
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can pass a function to the `data` argument in a geom:

```
# suppose you have your longer pipeline here
mtcars %>%
  ggplot()+
    geom_point(
      aes(wt, mpg),
      data = ~ filter(.x, cyl == 6), 
      colour = "red"
    ) +
    geom_point(
      aes(wt, mpg),
      data = ~ filter(.x, cyl == 4), 
      colour = "blue"
    )
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `. %>% [pipeline]` to create an anonymous function. The starting `.` is then a placeholder for the data passed to `ggplot2()`.

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot()+
    geom_point(
      aes(wt, mpg),
      data = . %>% filter(cyl == 6), 
      colour = "red"
    ) +
    geom_point(
      aes(wt, mpg),
      data = . %>% filter(cyl == 4), 
      colour = "blue"
    )
```

From the helpfile:

> A function will be called with a single argument, the plot data. The return value must be a data.frame, and will be used as the layer data. A function can be created from a formula (e.g. ~ head(.x, 10)).

Comment: Interesting! Though seems not to handle an anonymous function (which I’d tried to enable multiple subsequent additional operations on the filtered data)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "anonymous function"

Comment: Ah, with TJ's edit, no anonymous functioning is necessary :)

Comment: (FYI and anonymous function is a general programming term for a function the code defines but does not name because it is used immediately in the context in which it is defined. An example in a tidyverse chain would be `( dat %>% (function(x){print(x); return(x)}) %>% more_operations() ... )`, where the first function in the chain is an anonymous function.)

Comment: One interesting necessity when using `.` is that you can't just do `data = .`, it *has* to be used in a pipe `data = (. %>% identity() )`. But of course if we're not doing anything to the data we should just leave off `data =` in the first place, but thought I'd mention this as I encountered it and was left confused for a bit.